# If I do a REFRESH of Windows 10, will it remove all none-system apps I installed on a different logical dedicated apps-drive?

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, reset

I got a Lenovo G50-80 laptop *(1TB, 5400 rpm, 1.90Ghz, 12 GB)* that came pre-installed with windows 10. I then dual-booted it with Win81. My Win10 is now freezing five minutes at a time, saying it can't reach ... the C-drive!

The Win81 is installed on an adjacent partition, "D:\" 50GB
My apps are installed on "F:\", 326 GB

I am trying to split the logical "C:\" drive, 500GB into two logical drives:
- "C:\" of 100GB for the OS
- "E:\" of 400GB for the data.
I should've done this from the start, but I didn't know.

**My question: If I do only a refresh of Win10, (not a *reset*) will it still erase the apps I installed on a different  drive, my Apps Drive "F:\"** ???

None of the questions here was exactly like mine, so hence this new question.

Comment: No, not at all. But the programs data saved in OS drive may be affected. So not install the apps directly by installer. My preferred partition style will be `Win10 || Win81 || Apps || Data`

Comment: It won't delete your application but they will have to be reinstalled all the same.  How Refresh is well documented I will find the duplicate question later.  Speaking of Win32 applications that requires registry and dlls like Visual C++

Comment: I would use a virtual machine e.g. with VirtualBox. That way you can try out all kinds of solutions and see if they work before you try it on your real PC.

Comment: Thank you, @SpiderPig as always, you go right to the heart of my question. and don't ever engage in irelevant, wishful, nor that pesky Monday Night Quarterback hindsight thinking.

Comment: I'm serious here. Installing Win10 and 8 on a VM doesn't take long. If you did this you could easily find the answers to nearly all of the questions you asked here recently. It also takes a lot less time than you have spent on this site trying to get advice from someone else.

Comment: @SpiderPig Ain't got no room on my HDD for all that fancy stuff. However: What would happen if I Refreshed Win10, and the drive it sits on, is 80% full? Should it be less than 50% because of the back up it makes?

Comment: @GwenKillerby - If there is not enough space to install Windows 10, the Refresh process will fail, and the process will be reverted.